# Force git to push as locally configured user

Tags: git

I have two GitHub accounts that I am managing, let's say `accountX` and `accountY` In the beginning, I was using only one, so I had a global config with its username and email (accountX). Now I want to use the second one. I created a repo, I used `git config` to configure the username and email locally for this repo.

I made a commit, and `git log` shows a proper username and email (the ones configured locally, so the second account) under the commit. Then I've added a repo address (created on this second account) and I wanted to `git push`. Unfortunately, I get the message, that `accountX` doesn't have the permissions to this repo (and it shouldn't), but why isn't it using the one I configured locally? Is it because of my SSH key stored for the `accountX`? So I want to push via ssh and it uses a key generated way back in history for `accountX`?

Do you guys see my mistake here?

Comment: Did you set the SSH key for your second GitHub account?

Answer (score 0):

Using `git config user.xxx` commands is only for setting author and committer names, not for authentication.

For using the right account, you need to record a second SSH URL, using your second private key.

This is done through a `~/.ssh/config` file.

```
git remote add origin2 second
git push second master
```

With "`second`" being defined in the aforementioned  `~/.ssh/config` file.

```
Host second
   Hostname yourGitServer.com
   User git
   IdentityFile c:/path/to/your/second/private/key
```

Comment: I've added a second ssh key, so I have `id_rsa` and `id_rsa_accountY`. I've added the second public key to my `accountY` GitHub account, but still when I push it says that permission to repoXYZ is denied for `accountX`

Comment: Make sure your URL is using the host entry of your SSH config file, which references the right IdentityFile (or, your second SSH private key)